# Error from mongoose is not an instance of MongoError?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to capture the `E11000 duplicate key` error, so I deliberately insert the same user(uid is the key)

```
const MongoError = require('mongodb-core').MongoError
async function insertUser(uid) {
    try {
        await userModel.create({
            "uid": uid,
            "create_datetime": new Date(),
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.constructor)
        console.log(e instanceof MongoError)
    }
}
```

Using the Debugging tool, I can see the constructor of e is `class MongoError extends Error`, however the result of `e instanceof MongoError` is **false**, very strange!! anyone good advice?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this answers your actual question, but I don't believe the errors are meant to be caught like this. 
Rather, you should check if

```
error.name==='MongoError' && error.code === 11000
```

which is the recommended solution of Valeri Karpov, one of the core mongoose developers himself: https://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-error-handling 
(the article is from 2016, but I still believe it to be valid)

Answer (score 0):

It seems on the MongoDB documentation that it is the good way to handle the errors (see official doc link below).

But on my side I don't even succeed to require MongoServerError, I got "MongoServerError is undefined". I installed MongoDB NodeJS Driver with "npm i mongodb" but I also have mongoose installed and I connect to a remote Atlas mongodb server. Do you know how I should require MongoServerError?

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/index.html#error-handling

```
const client = new MongoClient(url);
await client.connect();
const collection = client.db().collection('collection');

try {
  await collection.insertOne({ _id: 1 });
  await collection.insertOne({ _id: 1 }); // duplicate key error
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
    console.log(`Error worth logging: ${error}`); // special case for some reason
  }
  throw error; // still want to crash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb driver instance that mongoose is using is exposed through mongoose.mongo, so you can do `e instanceof mongoose.mongo.MongoError`.

Requiring (and I suppose npm installing) mongodb-core explicitly probably gives you a different instance (copy) of the mongodb driver than the one mongoose is using. So `require('mongodb-core') !== mongoose.mongo` and `require('mongodb-core').MongoError !== mongoose.mongo.MongoError`.